# Efficient indexes for lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, indexing

I'm trying to understand the proper way to assign indexes on a lookup table. Given the following tables and sample query, what are the most efficient primary/additional indexes for the lookup table?

Table: items (id, title, etc.)

Table: categories (id, title, etc.)

Table: lookup (category_id, item_id, type, etc.)

```
SELECT * FROM items 
    INNER JOIN lookup ON
        lookup.item_id=items.id AND lookup.type="items" 
    INNER JOIN categories ON 
        categories.id=lookup.category_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i JOIN
     lookup l
     ON l.item_id = i.id AND l.type = 'items' JOIN 
     categories c
     ON c.id = l.category_id;
```

The best indexes are probably:

- `lookup(type, item_id)`
- `categories(id)`  (probably there already if `id` is a primary key)
- `items(id)`  (probably there already if `id` is a primary key)

Under some circumstances, this may not be a big improvement, particularly if most `lookup()` rows have a type of "items".

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the join predicates your query only has a single filering precate (`lookup.type = "items"`). If this predicate has a good selectivity (i.e. it selects 5% or less of the rows) then you should use it as the first column of the index. I would do:

```
create index ix1 on lookup (type, item_id, category_id)
```

If the `id` columns on the table `items` and `categories` represent the primary keys, then there's nothing else to do.

The engine will probably read the lookup table using the index, and then will read the other two tables using their PK indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not have an auto_incr id for the mapping table.

Have

```
 PRIMARY KEY(type, item_id, category_id),
 INDEX(category_id, type, item_id)
```

For the second index, will you need `type` when going from a category to an item?  If not, leave it out.

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Thanks!

To clarify: I have multiple data types, multiple taxonomies. Each taxonomy has a lookup table that can connect it to one or more data types because there may be other fields for data related to the association itself.

There are cases where one taxonomy is supported by many data types whereas others only support a couple. For this reason, the "type" field may filter a lot for one but less so for another.

The responses here seem to be in agreement. However, I'd note when there are both indexes above this query always prefers the latter one. Not sure why or if that is of concern.